# Building a VPN "Bridge"

Tags: networking, vpn

I have a Windows machine W that can connect to an off-site computer C via VPN. I also have a Linux machine L in the same LAN as W (but not as C).
Is it technically possible for L to use W's VPN connection to get access to C?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. For this to work, you need:

- A decent routing/gateway software running on **W** (I haven't done that on windows in 15 years, so I'll let you [google](https://www.google.no/search?q=windows%20gateway%20router&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=JyksVai8J4edsgHXp4CoDw#q=windows%20as%20router) this one)
- **L** needs a static route set up for the IP of **C**
- **W** needs a static route set up so that any requests for **C** coming in will get shoved into the VPN-network. The VPN client might take care of this already, tho.

Without knowing the exact IP schema between C, W, and L, that's as little vague as I can be.

---

Tip1: I just have to state the obvious, in case you haven't tried it. `vpnc` on **L** should let you connect to said VPN directly.

Comment: Sounds like it'll take me some time to get through all that stuff. I might get back to you with some questions during that process.  Do I also need to set up L so that it uses W as a gateway in some form? And no, unfortunately I cannot use L to connect to C directly as I need a smartcard on W to connect to C which I cannot use on L...

Comment: @Dunkit You do not set up L to use W as a default gateway, if that is what you're asking. This is what the static route is for. If done properly, anything intended to go to the VPN network goes to W. Anything else goes to your default gateway the way it did before.

Comment: I haven't done it but I like how your answer is so concise and covers the abstract. I wouldn't call that vague, it's quite specific in outlining the solution accurately. But you then say that without knowing the exact IP schema you can't go further.. that's not correct,  you can go further and make it even better by following on from the abstract theory you have written, putting in an example ip schema, suppose for example the LAN is 192.168.1.x and the VPN is 10.x.x.x  You should be able to show the commands and routing table for the linux machine, even if you can't for the windows machine.